# How to use a string to refer to a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have 3 data frames called 'first', 'second' and 'third'

I also have a string vector with their names in it

```
 frames <- c("first","second","third")
```

I would like to loop through the vector and refer to the data frames

```
for (i in frames) {

  #set first value be 0 in each data frame
  i[1,1] <- 0
}
```

This does not work, what am I missing?

Comment: Take a look at `?get` and/or `?assign` but also realize that there is probably a better way to do what you actually want to do.

Comment: I think you want `get(i)`.  But like Dason said, there is probably a better way. a list of data.frames for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really not the optimal way to do this but this is one way to make your specific example work.

```
first <- data.frame(x = 1:5)
second <- data.frame(x = 1:5)
third <- data.frame(x = 1:5)

frames <- c("first","second","third")

for (i in frames) {
 df <- get(i)
 df[1,1] <- 45
 assign(as.character(i), df, envir= .GlobalEnv)
}


> first
   x
1 45
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
> second
   x
1 45
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
> third
   x
1 45
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
```

Answer (score 2):

As Justin mentioned, R way would be to use a list. So given that you only have the data frame names as strings, you can copy them in a list.

```
frames <- lapply(c("first", "second", "third"), get)
(frames <- lapply(frames, function(x) {x[1,1] <- 0; x}))
```

However, you are working on a copy of `first`, `second` and `third` within `frames`.