# How to apply the same function to 1 column of different data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have multiple data frames in my R environment
eg. data1,data2,data3.
The first column is a date column having header 
"X"(same header in all data frames)but its class is showing as character. 
So i want to use as.Date() function on the first column of all the dataframes in my environment.

```
data1$X <- as.Date(data1$X)
```

The above line works fine for one data frame. But I Want to use a for loop 
    for all the data  frames. I have a list of the names of all the data frames.

```
list <- c("data1", "data2", "data3")
```

I tried doing the following

```
for (i in list) {
  i$x <- as.Date(i$x)
}
```

which doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your object `list` is a character vector. So at `i$x` you try something like `"data1"$x` (for example). BTW: "doesn't work" is not enough information, certainly you got an error message. Please put the error message in your question!

Comment: the error when i run                                                                                        for (i in list) {
  i$x <- as.Date(i$x)
}                                                                                                                                  is  Error in i$x : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `lapply` here to avoid `for` side effect:

```
lapply(c("data1","data2","data3"), function(dx){
  dx <- transform(dx,as.Date(x))
})
```

Comment: can you please elaborate how the following line of code works function(dx){
  dx <- transform(dx,as.Date(x)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
date.columns <- c('date1','date2','date3') # all date columns
df[date.columns] <- lapply(df[date.columns], as.Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `for` loop to evaluate the data frame name (`i`) and the variable name (`x`) properly, you need to use `[""]` notation. Try the following:

```
for (i in list) {
  i["x"] <- as.Date(i["x"])
}
```

If this doesn't work post an example of your data using `dput()` (see [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example))

Comment: the above code runs but there is no change in the class of the dates column

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but nobody gave the OP a satisfying answer.
Here is a similar question

[How to use a string to refer to a data frame in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897590/how-to-use-a-string-to-refer-to-a-data-frame-in-r)

Using `get` and `assign`

```
for (i in list) {
  df <- get(i)
  df$X <- as.Date(df$X)
  assign(as.character(i), df, envir= .GlobalEnv)
}
```

Here you are working with copies